# OrderedDict - For Loop - Delete current iterated value?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key-value, ordereddictionary

I need to compare current iteration of an OrderedDict's value with the previous iteration and then remove that current iteration if it is smaller than the previous. But when I use `int()` to do so, it returns `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

How do I make it so that it evaluates the two values as integers and remove that `key:value` item in the OrderedDict if it is smaller than the previous iteration?

```
for key, value in OrderedDict(left_score_dict).items():
        if int(value) < int(value)-1:
            del left_score_dict[key]
```

Is there some kind of dictionary comprehension that can used here to convert the OrderedDict's values to integers, either temporary in the expression or permanently?

Thank you!

P.S.: Quite the beginner over here.

Comment: The error says `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` So you probably have an empty string as a value, wherever you expected an int. Clean up the dict before running this code?